# Where in memory are global variables stored?

Tags: memory-management

I would like to know where in memory the global variables are stored. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dude, this was the FIRST goddamn link on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588767/where-in-memory-are-my-variables-stored-in-c
Did you even try that one?

Comment: Also, here is...a result from the 4th result. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/
Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @SyedAliHamza While you're right to point out that this question is trivially answerable using standard resources, there's absolutely no need to be rude about it. Please [be nice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @DavidRicherby, "maybe" I was being rude. Probably subconsciously. I'll keep that in mid.

Comment: @SyedAliHamza When you start using shoutycaps and curse words, that's pretty much the definition of rude. I'm glad it wasn't intentional, but please do keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This really just depends on the compiler you're using and the architecture you're targeting. For instance, I could make a compiler which assigns global variables to general purpose registers in bank 2 of a PIC16f887a microcontroller. It's arbitrary. This is a bad question.